# cursor.fetchone() returns NoneType but it has value, how to collect values in a list?

Tags: python, postgresql, typeerror, database-cursor

```
def get_user_data(username: str, columns: list):
    result = []
    for column in columns:
        query = f"SELECT {column} FROM ta_users WHERE username = '{username}'"
        cursor.execute(query)
        print('cursor.fetchone() from loop = ', cursor.fetchone(),
              'type= ', type(cursor.fetchone()))  # debug
        fetchone = cursor.fetchone()
        result.append(fetchone[0])
```

raises:

> ```
> result.append(fetchone[0])
> ```
>
> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

the print above returns:

> cursor.fetchone() from loop =  ('6005441021308034',) type=  <class
> 'NoneType'>

I read why it can return None, but i did not figure out how to work around it.

how to make it work and return list of values after the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are "emptying" it in the first `fetchone()` run, that's why you are getting `None` in the following (it looks for the second record, but can't find it. Try this code:

```
def get_user_data(username: str, columns: list):
    result = []
    for column in columns:
        query = f"SELECT {column} FROM ta_users WHERE username = '{username}'"
        cursor.execute(query)
        res = cursor.fetchone()
        print('cursor.fetchone() from loop = ', res,
              'type= ', type(res)))  # debug
        if res:
            result.append(res[0])
```